# Параметры в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Имеется класс

```
public class ModbusConfig
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Имя последовательного порта, соответствующего аппарату
    /// </summary>
    public string Port { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Скорость обмена
    /// </summary>
    public int BaudRate { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// ВРемя ожидания ответа
    /// </summary>
    public int Timeout { get; set; }
}
```

Весь проект с этим классом объединен одним пространством имен. Как добавить тип ModBusConfig в параметры, так чтобы на него можно было ссылаться следующим образом

```
return Settings.Default.ModBusConfig;
```

В окне Параметры проекта в выпадающем списке данного пространства имен нет и по кнопке обзор тоже ничего [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо нажать "Обзор...", затем в появившемся окне в строке поиска (у меня она называется "Selected type:" поскольку английская студия) вписать: <Ваш namespase>.ModbusConfig и нажать ОК. Нужный тип добавится.